# Expanding an encrypted partition in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I was running 18.04 LTS on a 320GB hard drive on a fully encrypted install and I recently upgraded to a 1TB hard drive.  I made a disk image on my external drive and restored the system on to the new 1TB drive.  After restoring, I attempted to expand the partition using gparted to the full disk size but was unable.  After doing some research, I found that gparted does not allow you to manipulate encrypted partitions so now I’m in search of a way ahead.  Can anyone help me with step by step direction on how to expand the encrypted partition?

Comment: This wiki covers resizing encrypted partitions in Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Comment: Comar, thank you for the feed back. I'll check out the wiki page to see if I can figure it out from there.